# Swift 3 Upgrade Issues Conversion

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

When I try to compile the repo https://github.com/Bernie-2016/fieldthebern-ios I run into a swift conversion issue. "This workspace has projects that contain source code with an earlier version of swift."

"Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly."

When I try "edit -> convert -> To current swift syntax" Opens up selecting targets to convert, many of which are frameworks. Proceeding with the conversion yields >3,000 errors in the console.

I think the solution is to grab the latest libraries via cocoapods and then complete the conversion with the main project code but am not getting any luck.

Comment: That's definitely the solution. You require a Swift 3 version of each and every framework you have. Go check the repositories for those frameworks and ensure that they have a Swift 3 branch/tag or that their master branch is now on Swift 3. You'll want to point your podfile at these Swift 3 versions and recreate the project with that before trying to convert.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your podfile references a Swift 3 branch for every Framework.

Then you need to `cd` into your project folder using `Terminal`

Run: `pod update`

once done, open your project in Xcode and you should be prompted to convert into the latest Swift Syntax automatically, if you weren't you have to do it manually in

`Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…`

when all changes are prompted, click update

this will again display 999+ errors but no worries.

run the clean command `Cmd + Shift + K` and then build `Cmd + B`

you should have no more errors and if you do have errors, they shouldn't be a lot and you would have to go through the errors manually to fix them

its completely normal, it became a routine thing for me when using CocoaPods